# Tag links between SO, SF and SU

Tags: feature-request, tags, tag-wiki, site-crossover, tag-dropdown

Consider python tag. It's programming, so belongs to Stack Overflow. System administrators hack scripts in it (and manage applications written in it), so it belongs to Server Fault. Power users use it too (I use it as a pocket calculator all the time) so it also belongs to Super User.

I think that it would be cool to quickly see what other angles of particular topic are discussed on sister projects by providing links to the `questions/tagged/python` path on the other sites.

Comment: This seems like a good idea. It might help users figure out which site to post their question on, especially if it also showed the wiki excerpt when hovering over the links.

Answer (score 1):

You really already have this. All these sites offer Atom feeds for tag or tag combinations, leaving you free to mix and match as desired.

[For instance - here's the combined python feed you were after...](http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.run?_id=YjiOiw963hGbCWWNKX1_0w&_render=rss).

Took me maybe ten minutes to put together, and i've never used Y! Pipes before; i suspect if i took the time to familiarize myself with it, i could parametrize it for arbitrary tag combinations.