# My SU/SO/MSO/SF feeds in a Single RSS?

Tags: feature-request, stack-exchange, feed

I'm not sure how these websites are setup behind the scenes, so I don't know how ridiculous a request like this really is. Would it be possible to get  a single RSS output of all my activity across all four sites?

Granted, I could build my own PHP script to routinely pull them all together, but that would just stink :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Yahoo! Pipes](http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/).

It's dead easy. [I've only used it once](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9793/tag-links-between-so-sf-and-su/9799#9799), and it still took me only a matter of minutes to pull together feeds from multiple sites, sort them, and produce a single combined feed.

---

**Edit:** OK, [now I've used it twice](http://pipes.yahoo.com/shog9/seuseractivity). That link will take you to a page where you can enter your user IDs for the various sites, and get in return a custom, combined RSS feed of all your activity across all four of them. Have fun...

[image: piping]

Comment: Doesn't mix all items together. SF 10:53AM appears after SU 11:00AM.

Comment: That's where you use a sorter to sort by the timestamp.

Comment: Related: [Jeff, Why did you block Yahoo! Pipes?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23826/jeff-why-did-you-block-yahoo-pipes) (Not sure if that block is still in effect.)

Answer (score 3):

[Google Reader](http://www.google.com/reader) allow you to do this.

Any RSS feeds you subscribe to with it can be placed in folders together. So for example, you could create a Stack Overflow folder, and add to it all your SO-and-friends feeds.

Thereafter, clicking on the folder name will show you all new items on all the feeds inside it, in one go.

Here's one I made earlier:

[image: Google reader screenshot]

Comment: ++This looks like the easier - and probably overall better - solution.