# Can I get a customized RSS-feed?

Tags: feature-request, tags

Can I get a customized RSS-feed in Stack Overflow, based on "interested" and "ignore" tags?

Comment: Already asked here, vote it up and bump it: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3403/rss-feed-of-your-interesting-tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Yahoo [Pipes](http://pipes.yahoo.com/) to build it yourself?

Comment: It seems that every page that could be useful is blocked from Pipes accessing it by robots.txt.

Comment: Yepp: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23826/jeff-why-did-you-block-yahoo-pipes

Answer (score 1):

Easiest IMO is to search for the tags (e.g. search for `[-spring][java]`).
There is a RSS-feed link at the bottom of the result page:

[alt text http://img522.imageshack.us/img522/2488/rssf.jpg](http://img522.imageshack.us/img522/2488/rssf.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

There was a podcast where Jeff talked about this, but I'm having trouble finding it. I know he talked about tags for sure, but I thought there was also an RSS feed.

Answer (score 0):

Or use:
https://meta.stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag/tags%20or%20reputation