# Out of curiosity, why does SO consider Yahoo Slurp as 'evil'?

Tags: discussion, robots

I was looking at [robots.txt on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/robots.txt) and noticed that [Yahoo Slurp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yahoo!_Slurp) was considered evil. I'm just wondering why?

Excerpt:

```
#
# Yahoo bot is evil.
#
User-agent: Slurp
Disallow: /
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It was explained [in the blog](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/the-perfect-web-spider-storm/) a year ago, and I guess things have [not really](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23826/jeff-why-did-you-block-yahoo-pipes/23853#23853) changed:

```
User-Agent           Requests      Bytes Served
Yahoo! Slurp/3.0       56,331     1,124,861,780
Googlebot/2.1          56,579       773,418,834
Mediapartners-Google   30,519       671,904,609
```

...and then, after some specific settings did not help:

> In the meantime, since Yahoo (via Slurp!) is about 0.3% of our traffic, but insists on rudely consuming a huge chunk of our prime-time bandwidth, they’re getting IP banned and blocked. I’m a bit more sympathetic to Google, since they deliver almost 90% of our traffic, but it sure would be nice if they’d allow me to at least schedule the massive web spider storms for off-peak hours...

Comment: Strange, I've never seen it do that, but thanks :) +1 and marking correct, that's indeed why they banned it.

Comment: I guess that's why they called it Slurp!

Comment: Does SO, which is used from around the web, really got off-peak hours? just curious. Also statistics might be evil, because if used by referrals, Yahoo\Verizon may hide what traffic they bring. But I agree, Verizon is *evil*, so Yahoo might be too.