# Is the Firefox browser's default search engine still evil in 2014?

Tags: discussion, search-engine, robots

From `/robots.txt` on one Stack Exchange site:

```
#
# Yahoo bot is evil.
#
User-agent: Slurp
Disallow: /
```

[Four years ago, someone asked what's so "evil" about Yahoo!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53502/out-of-curiosity-why-does-so-consider-yahoo-slurp-as-evil), and the answer was that Slurp was making too many requests during peak hours. Is this still the case? And how will this affect inbound traffic from search engines to Stack Exchange sites now that [Mozilla has switched default web search in Firefox from Google to Yahoo!](http://www.computerworld.com/article/2853435/mozilla-will-automatically-switch-firefox-search-to-yahoo-for-most-us-users.html)?

Comment: I see the manipulation in the title you did. ;)

Comment: 1. Firefox has only about 11% browser market share. 2. Users can still change their search engine preference. 3. I don't think Stack Exchange users can be lumped in with "most users" who "do not change the default settings of their software."

Comment: The other 'bot only **says** it does no evil.

Comment: If it was _really_ evil, it wouldn't honor robots.txt.

Comment: @FishBelowtheIce maybe that's exactly what the comment means: "It won't follow this rule anyway but it might as well be here"

Comment: http://duckduckgo.com is the only non-evil search engine!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since 2009, *Yahoo Search* [doesn’t crawl anymore](https://help.yahoo.com/kb/search/SLN2214.html). They use *Bing’s* index instead.

And as the robots.txt files of the Stack Exchange sites (for example, [for this Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/robots.txt)) don’t disallow crawling for `bingbot`, you can find SE content by using *Yahoo Search* just fine:

http://search.yahoo.com/search?p=site%3Astackexchange.com+Is+the+Firefox+browser%27s+default+search+engine+still+evil+in+2014%3F

While [*Yahoo! Slurp*](https://help.yahoo.com/kb/search/SLN22600.html) is no longer used for crawling content for *Yahoo Search*, it still has some other purposes, e.g., crawling of "partner sites" for inclusion in *Yahoo News/Finance/Sports*, and to "confirm accuracy and improve Yahoo's personalized content" for *Yahoo Search*.