# Is Stack Exchange explicitly blocking web crawlers that have a potential to be used for training AI models?

Tags: support, status-review, chatgpt, web

The [`robots.txt`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/robots.txt) for all SE sites explicitly blocks GPTBot and Amazonbot.

[GPTBot](https://platform.openai.com/docs/gptbot) is OpenAI's web crawler that is used for training their large language models as well as allowing their applications to retrieve content from current live web pages based on user requests. [Amazonbot](https://developer.amazon.com/support/amazonbot) is a web crawling bot used to improve Amazon services (which may or may not include services such as [Comprehend](https://aws.amazon.com/comprehend/) and [CodeWhisperer](https://aws.amazon.com/codewhisperer/)) and give Alexa services access to live web pages.

I'm focusing the question on these specific bots. I was able to find information and discussions about voltron/008 and Bytespider. Site owners and administrators have reported that these bots excessively crawl and access resources. [Yahoo Pipes (although defunct) is addressed in an early Meta question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/23826/572). However, I am unable to find similar reports for GPTBot and Amazonbot, so I'd like to understand the rationale behind blocking these crawlers.

**What is the rationale for blocking these specific bots from crawling any SE pages? And, more generally, what is the process used to determine if a bot should be blocked from crawling SE sites?**

Comment: Related from MSO: [Will Stack Overflow disallow the GPT web crawler?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/425960/11082165) and [Why has Stack Overflow banned the GPT web crawler?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/425989/) (now deleted)

Comment: So my curious question is, why does it matter if they are blocking web crawlers that may be used for AI model training in light of the policy to disallow ChatGPT-centric answers on the site?  Like, what is the value of an answer in this context?

Comment: @Makoto Ensuring access to content has nothing to do with the type of content allowed. That's like asking why it matters if a crawler is blocked because we disallow rude and offensive answers on the site. Depending on the answer to this question, I have a number of follow up questions that also need to be addressed.

Comment: I mean, I'm just not seeing why one should care, is all.  They disallowed this crawler.  So what?  What are you really trying to angle at here?

Comment: @Makoto As a contributor, I care about why access to the content that I create and share under the terms of a free and open license is being restricted. And that is what is happening here. OpenAI and Amazon are being blocked from accessing my content through this platform, and the decision was made unilaterally by the company with no input from contributors. As a contributor, I simply want to understand the rationale behind the decision and, generally, how the decision is made regarding other crawlers.

Comment: Oh, so this *isn't* a question about why a crawler is banned.  It's a question about whether or not the company is overreaching when they explicitly prohibit something like OpenAI from accessing the data via robots.  Going to say that this is already a well-settled pattern; the company can absolutely choose to republish content in any way they wish, and this is not in violation of any license that has already been pre-established.  CC-by-SA does not prescribe a delivery vehicle for the content published by it, nor does it mandate that data be available 100% free-of-charge.

Comment: @Makoto Maybe. Maybe not. It depends on the rationale for blocking the crawler. Blocking the crawler because they behave poorly and risk the stability of the network is a fundamentally different decision than blocking the crawler simply because it's being used to train an AI model. The company _can_ choose to control how material is distributed, but _why_ and _how_ that choice is made matters. So let's start with how and why the decision was made before going to the next step.

Comment: Back when the data dumps were turned off for the sake of trying to get things like ChatGPT and other AI bots to pay money for the data set that Stack Overflow had (a-la "closing the barn door after the horse bolted"), the community was furious because the company had broken *their* tacit promise/guarantee that this would be happening.  That delivery method is orthogonal to either bots scraping the site or API access, and has nothing to do with CC-by-SA itself, but is a quarterly upload of data that the original leadership committed the service to provide.

Comment: I'm going to forcefully say that it **does not matter** why the company chooses to ban scrapers on the site.  If they don't want the traffic coming from that kind of client, that is entirely within their wont to decide.  If you're concerned about your data *not* being made available to bots to train on, then the bots *could*, in practice, just use the data dumps.  Or, they could use Stack Overflow's curated/cleaned data set, whenever that's available for purchase.  This is why I struggle to see what you're in a huff about here.

Comment: @Makoto I don't care that _you_ don't see the problem. I see a problem and I want answers. There is no other way to go about requesting these answers from the company.

Comment: It matters... *to some people*. It doesn't matter from the perspective of honoring the license that the data exists under. It's fair to be concerned and want answers, but it's certainly not a case of SE interfering with the usage of our content as allowed by the license. (which i don't think is what you're arguing anyway)

Comment: @KevinB If I understand you right, yes. I'm definitely not arguing that SE can't do what they are doing, especially in a legal context. However, understanding these policies is important to me (and likely other contributors). Who has access to our contributions on this platform, who is being blocked, why, and how these decisions are made are all important to consider. Not only should the decisions and policies be up for discussion among the affected contributors, but it may impact how people may want to make their contributions available on other platforms.

Comment: @ThomasOwens: Nothing's stopping you from making contributions elsewhere, even if you were using stuff you posted on Stack Overflow.  The only limiting factor is that wherever it's posted it has to abide by CC-by-SA.

Comment: @Makoto Other than effort. But even so, since I own the content, I can post it anywhere regardless of the license the other place abides by. I'd rather understand the restrictions that SE is putting on my contributions so I can make informed decisions about how to proceed.

Comment: This is why I struggle with your complaint.  Blocking bots and crawlers from making connections and draining resources is such a *mundane, routine thing to do* when hosting a website that it seems pointless to complain about.  Stack Exchange has no obligation to publish your content either, so whether or not bots can scrape the content at all is just a settled debate.  If your sentiment is that Stack Exchange should allow these kinds of bots to scrape data so that your data can be a part of an LLM, then that's a question about expense, which would justify them charging for the data.

Comment: @Makoto Historically, content has been open and accessible. Yahoo Pipes was blocked because it crawled excessively and did not respect robots.txt for what not to crawl, for example. There are similar reports for other blocked bots. There is no evidence that I can find that Amazonbot and GPTBot are abusive or draining resources from human users of the platform. If they are indeed respectful and the only reason they were blocked was because they train AI models, that's a conversation that contributors need to be a part of and not a unilateral decision on the part of the company.

Comment: Some of the reasons a bot may be blocked could be explicitly related to that bot’s behavior. Like the question ban, the details behind such a ban (“blocked because x, y, z”) are unlikely to be made public, as that would give other bots more info to evade/skirt. IMO, anyway. I doubt it’s just because they’re bots, plenty of other bots and crawlers and models have been allowed even through all the anti-AI sentiment recently. (Well, anti-let-other-parties-do-AI-stuff.)

Comment: @Stuckat1337 I don't think the explicit details are necessary. However, understanding if it was due to observed behavior and, in the most general terms, what kinds of behaviors would trigger a bot being blocked is important. Also understanding if the company is engaging with the companies behind them to ensure the bots are better behaved. The expectations of human behavior on the network are well understood. The expectations of automated tools are not. And, of course, if it isn't because of the behavior, that opens up a new conversation.

Comment: Well, as mentioned, they’re running a web site and, like any other site, have the right to block automated tools for whatever reason they feel like. I don’t think they really owe you an explanation, and I don’t really know if anyone cares about how much evidence _you_ have seen of bad behavior from this specific thing, but I do wish you luck on your expedition to get one.

Comment: If a bot behaves badly, it’s going to get blocked. I don’t think it matters whether the bot’s goal is to train some model or not. Many, many, many bots have been blocked and there has been little fanfare about any of them. This one seems to be cherry-picked because AI is a hot button topic and it’s a good way to ensure lots of engagement here. If you have such distrust in SE that you think they’re purposely banning bots solely to make your content less consumable, a more productive thing to do would probably be to stop contributing here.

Comment: @Stuckat1337 There are 8 crawlers blocked in robots.txt. 008, Voltron, and Bytespider have been discussed in other venues as being known to have some less-than-desired behaviors. GPTBot, Amazonbot, and now (more recently) Google-Extended were added, but there is no documented bad behavior. If there is bad behavior, it should be announced. If not, understanding why they were blocked is of extreme importance to me. Of course, other bots may be blocked at a level where we can't see, but it's worth having that discussion too.

Comment: Just because it's of extreme importance _to you_ doesn't mean they suddenly need to start announcing why they make every temporary or permanent IP/UserAgent decision they make. And as I suggested before, just because it's not publicly documented doesn't mean there _isn't_ bad behavior, and there may very well be plausible reasons why they're not "announcing" anything. A lot of "stopping bad behavior" actions are purposely secret / vague / obscure because more information only helps the attacker. And not helping the attacker, IMO, should be way more important than satisfying your curiosity.

Comment: I guess I'll just link this question once again for now: [Is SE [going to be\] selling our content for AI model training? [...\]](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/388551/241919). Not confirmed yet, but very likely.

Comment: Suddenly, ["Prevent datadump use"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/389922/june-2023-data-dump-is-missing) vibes... I see a pattern here, do you see one also?

Comment: "As a contributor, I care about why access to the content that I create and share under the terms of a free and open license is being restricted."  OpenAI is not abiding by the CC BY-SA license that you released your content under.  They are generating derivative works without attribution.

Comment: @endolith That is not correct. The current direction (in the US, anyway) is that it is acceptable to train models on copyrighted data and such training does not require a license since the patterns that are extracted are not copyrightable (and, therefore, not subject to any license). The model is not a derivative work. There are still open questions about people who use such trained models and their legal (and ethical) obligations to ensure that output they use does not infringe on someone else's work and that proper credit is given.

Comment: @ThomasOwens The "patterns that are extracted" are verbatim copies of the original content:

https://arxiv.org/abs/2202.07646 

https://arxiv.org/abs/2301.13188 

https://cdn.arstechnica.net/wp-content/uploads/2023/03/948c88f4-e3d8-4123-ab42-7f681e70ad01_1600x1142.webp 

https://bair.berkeley.edu/blog/2020/12/20/lmmem/

https://twitter.com/stefankarpinski/status/1410971061181681674

Comment: @endolith That's nice, but that's not how the courts (again, in the US) are viewing this. Of course, these cases are still working through the legal process and there may be legislation that changes things. But until then, for deciding matters of law, we can only go by what courts have decided. I'm not sure how courts in other jurisdictions are deciding on similar matters, since I don't follow them as closely. As of now, the current thinking is that it is legal to use copyrighted data for training models without needing to obtain an appropriate license.

Comment: @ThomasOwens If a language model is producing verbatim copies of CC-licensed content without attributing it to the author, it's pretty clearly a violation of the license, and therefore a copyright violation.  We or SE should be suing OpenAI, etc. for using our content without permission.

Comment: @endolith Yes. There are still open questions as to if that is the legal responsibility of the model creator or the person using the model to generate content. I'm not aware of any decisions on this matter yet. There are also ethical questions about what obligations may be, regarding things like sources used for training or detecting output that may infringe on the rights of authors of training data, but these are philosophical discussions and not legal ones.

Comment: @ThomasOwens How would the person using the model be responsible for what the model was trained on and what it outputs?  They have no way to even know where the content came from, so are incapable of properly attributing it...

Comment: @endolith if the user is republishing the model outputs, they could maybe be held responsible for some things.

Comment: @endolith SE isn't the one being infringed, we are, and who, among "we", are going to foot the legal bills? SE content has been scraped and abused without attribution for as long as SE has existed and no such consequences have been enforced.

Comment: @endolith Not knowing does not absolve one of guilt of a crime. But also, Kevin is correct - SE's stance has, historically, been that they cannot enforce our rights. I don't believe that it's right for SE to selectively enforce our rights without engaging us. I am in favor of my open-source content being used for model training, but I also believe that model creators need to do a better job of identifying the data they used for training and finding ways to incorporate that data into output. But we need to work with the current as-is state.

Comment: @ThomasOwens If you want your content to be used for training AI models without attribution, you are free to re-publish it under a different license, such as CC0, but the content you published on SE is under the CC BY-SA license by default: https://stackoverflow.com/help/licensing

Comment: @endolith Do you not understand how copyright and licensing work? I don't need to republish, since training (currently, in the US) does not require a license. It does not infringe upon my rights to use any material for training, including those that are not licensed. This is about SE implementing platform functionality to restrict what people want to do that is legally allowed. It should be done as part of a conversation and not unilaterally. If, after discussion, the community decides that it is best to block such crawlers, then people who want their content to be used can republish it.

Comment: Wow no answer yet. What a shock! I'm shocked, shocked!

Comment: Yeah, and a lot of misunderstanding of CC license requirements here in the comments. Scraping/robots.txt is not remotely orthagonal to the dumps, for one. Problem is, as long as community members like @makato incorrectly defend problematic business processes, there's little incentive for SE to respond directly.