# Link to other SE sites on tag-specific page?

Tags: discussion, tags, related-questions, site-crossover

As users become more familiar with tag wikis, I suspect that they click on a tag like [security](/questions/tagged/security) to learn more & they find a list of [tagged questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/security).

Similar in nature to [this request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9793/tag-links-between-so-sf-and-su), could the tagged questions page also include links to related content on **other Stack Exchange sites**? This would, by nature, increase traffic to related sites & *possibly* decrease migration?

For example, there is a [security](/questions/tagged/security) tag on many of the Stack Exchange sites:

[security](/questions/tagged/security) on Stack Overflow, and related content:

- [On Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/security)
- [On Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/security)
- [On Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/security)
- [On Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/security)
- [On Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/security)
- [On Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/security)
- [On Programmers](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/security)
- [On Tex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/security)
- [On User Experience](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/security)
- [On Web Applications](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/security)
- [On Geographic & Information Systems](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/security)
- [On Android Enthusiasts](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/security)
- And hey, [IT **Security**](https://security.stackexchange.com/)

And perhaps less related to the common theme, but the list continues:

- [On Home Improvement](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/security)
- [On Bicycles](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/security)

**Note:** I'd love to have this cross-site info on the tag suggestion popup, but I think this would be a nice step on that path.  We could point users to the tag wiki & tagged questions where they'd then see a list of related information on the other sites.