# Can tag subscription be universal throughout all SE sites?

Tags: feature-request, tags

As we see, some interrelated SE sites like SO and programmers.SE has numerous common tags. As someone subscribes to a tag, it seems that that tag is interesting to him/her. So, we can assume that s/he will be interested to question tagged with that specific one regardless of from which sub SE site it is. But now the tags are site-specific, not universal. So, people are not being notified about new questions s/he might be interested in. And OP's are deprived of getting better responses.

So I request to make tag subscription universal throughout all SE sites. Or, the whole tag management(FAQ/Info/Top users) can be generalized to be universal within all SE sites. Then the users can get more about the things they are interested in.

Comment: The [filters](http://stackexchange.com/filters/popular) page on Stack Exchange may be of interest to you.

Comment: It won't be like adding a favorite tag on one of the sites, but you can get email updates on these filters.  Click the little envelope underneath one of the popular ones, or create your own on the `My Filters` page.  I'm not claiming that it meets your requirements completely, but it comes close and is already in place.

Comment: @jonsca the creating or using these filters are a bit lengthy process. I want to have it as easy as subscribing to a tag.

Comment: Okay.  See how it goes.

Comment: @jonsca I realized that these filters can be used personally and thus deleted my previous comment. But as I have said, it's more like an advanced user option. I use SE frequently. But I came to know about it just now. So, I can tell there are many users who doesn't know about this feature. But tag subscription is sooo easy. Even you don't have to be a member of this site for RSS.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this is a good idea:

- Tags of the same name on different sites can have very different semantic meanings. Consider, for example, [my suggestion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103486/link-to-other-se-sites-on-tag-specific-page) for at least making this information available on the tag page.
- I think it would require a great deal more infrastructure to note which tags are related and which aren't.
- Filters can accomplish this.  I think filters should be more widely advertised as they are (from a user exp pov) on par with the breadth of knowing about on-topic questions on all stack exchange sites.

Perhaps we could consider adding a filter link on the tag wiki excerpts, on the tag wiki itself, or on the tag hover popup?

Comment: I think managing tag relations will not be so difficult. Tags having same names are linked automatically(or they are just same tags), unless there's a rule to differentiate them. Regarding filters, I agree with you that it should be configured to use more easily and advertised more.